# Development/runtime Licensing mechanism for a C# class library?

Tags: c#, licensing, class-library, license-key

I'm developing a .Net class library (a data provider) and I'm starting to think about how I would handle licensing the library to prospective purchasers.  By licensing, I mean the mechanics of trying to prevent my library from being used by those who haven't purchased it, not the software license (i.e., Apache, Gnu, etc).

I've never dealt with licensing, and in the past, I've always developed apps, not libraries.  I don't want to make things difficult for my customers; know it is not possible to make it ironclad.  Just some mechanism that gives me decent protection without making the customer jump through hoops or gnash their teeth.

I think the mechanism would check for a valid license when the class is being used in development mode, and not in runtime mode (when the customer's software is released to their customers).  I think libraries are typically sold per developer, but I'm not sure how that could be accomplished without making the mechanism odious for my customers; maybe that gets left to the honor system.

I Googled this and found many approaches.  Ideally, I'd like to do something that is generally accepted and common, the "right" way class libraries are licensed, if that exists, rather than making my customers deal with yet another license mechanism. A firm push in the right direction will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: That isn't a good title.  What you're talking about has nothing to do with licensing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the .NET supplied solution

http://www.ddj.com/web-development/184416695

Comment: The mechanism described in the article works fine for any kind of .NET Assembly. I have used it for WinForms, WebForms components, but also assemblies with just datastructures/types and algorithms (and no UI at all)

Comment: Thanks :-)  Docs on this from MS: [How to: License Components and Controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/fe8b1eh9(v=vs.120)]) - "We're no longer updating this content regularly" - but the underlying [`system.componentmodel.license`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.license?view=net-5.0) is still current/availab.e as at now/.NET 5.0

Answer (score 0):

When your client instantiates your class library, you would in your constructor code check for licensing. If the vendor does not have a valid/missing license, then you can throw a licensing exception. This would prevent someone from using your class/library. You should only do this once such that if the licensing is valid in one class, all your other classes would skip the licensing check.